# nested if else statements in python

Tags: python, if-statement, nested

I was wondering if you can do something like the following:

```
if(condition):
    if(condition:
         if(condition):
             print("some text")
         else:
             print("some more text")
    else:
         print("text")
else:
     print("Text")
```

My main question is that I get an error when I try to run multiple nested if statements?

Thanks

Comment: This is all very legal python, except for your second `if` which is missing a closing paren.

Comment: You are missing a `)` on one of your conditions.

Comment: You don't need the parentheses to begin with.

Comment: Also, using an apparently random number of spaces from 4 to 6 for each indent level is a very good way to get an `IndentationError` that's a pain to debug. Why not just stick with a consistent 4 spaces?

Comment: More generally, a question that just says "I get an error when I try to run multiple nested if statements" isn't very useful. Show us an actual [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)—complete code that we can run (that means at least defining `condition`), the expected output, and the traceback for the error you get.

Comment: It's legal but don't do it. Think how you can improve your logic.

Comment: thanks everyone just curious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encourage you to flatten your code, nested if's are real pain in the back for debbuging and maintaining your code. You can rewrite this as:

```
if condition1 and condition2 and condition3:
    print("some text")
elif condition1 and condition2 and not condition3:
    print("some more text")
elif condition1 and not contition2:
    print("text")
else:
    print("Text")
```

This might seem too verbose, but in makes it much easier to see if you have all important cases covered.

Comment: Although I do wonder about the performance penalty of doing this.  In the OP's code, each branch would not have to be tried multiple times, whereas here, each condition would have to be tested multiple times.

Comment: If condition is costly, you can assign result to a bool - which usually helps with readability too. And CPU time is usually much cheaper than developers' hours. It is good to keep performance in mind, but there are usually more important considerations... Unless you find a bottleneck, readability and maintainability beats microptimizing.

Comment: @mattingly890 premature optimizations is the root of all evil.  The cost would be minimal in most cases.

Comment: If you're so concerned with performance that how many `if` statements you use is important to you, you shouldn't be using Python to begin with.